# How to delete cache of Microsoft Teams on macOS?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

I want to delete the cache of the Microsoft Teams on my Macbook Air.

Because even after removing my profile pic in Microsoft teams. It shows the same profile pic as before even after restarting the application.

Can I clear data from this app on macOS using the app or cleaning some files?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are multiple locations with Teams cache files:

- as noted by @JMY1000, the regular cache folder `~/Library/Caches`
- see [@grg's answer here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/407427/121968) or [this answer by a Microsoft employee](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_other-mso_mac-mso_2019/multiple-teams-issues-on-mac/6d0a87f6-9ad8-4458-84f5-1bd5a82f0d3d): `~/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/Teams`

If you remove just those, you don't need to login again, so the following Terminal commands would work:

```
cd ~/Library/Caches
rm -rf com.microsoft.teams

cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/Microsoft/Teams
rm desktop-config.json
rm storage.json
rm Network\ Persistent\ State

rm -rf *Cache*
rm -rf blob_storage
rm -rf databases
rm -rf IndexedDB
rm -rf Local\ Storage
rm -rf tmp
```

---

For those who prefer a solution outside Terminal:

- open Finder
- open the 'Go' menu, choose 'Go to Folder...'

  - (or alternatively, use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>)
- enter `~/Library/Caches` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- delete the `com.microsoft.teams` folder

[image]

- Similarly, go to the `~/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/Teams` folder and delete these folders and files:

```
blob_storage
Cache
Code Cache
databases
desktop-config.json
GPUCache
IndexedDB
Local Storage
Network Persistent State
storage.json
tmp
```

Comment: I had one particular contact for whom I could not see my chat history & this fixed it - thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Teams stores caches in the following locations.

- `~/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/Teams`
- `~/Library/Caches/com.microsoft.teams`

Remove these folders using Finder to empty the cache.

1. Quit Teams.
2. In Finder, choose Go → Go to Folder and paste the above paths.

You will have to log in again after deleting these folders.